# Convert irrational fraction to rational one

Tags: python, python-2.7, fractions

What is the simplest method to convert variable like

```
x=7.36/1
```

into rational fraction like

```
x=736/100
```

Comment: That isn't valid syntax; is `x` a string? Have you looked into the [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html)?

Comment: Then you should definitely follow the link in the second part of my comment. Note that the fraction form should actually be `184/25`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from fractions import Fraction

Fraction(7.36/1).limit_denominator()
```